# I saved my iOS 5 SHSH with TinyUmbrella, and now I have 4.1 SHSH too?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod, firmware

I launched "Save SHSH" from TinyUmbrella (for the first time ever), and now in Saved SHSHs for iPod Touch list i get iPod 3G 4.1

Does this mean I can downgrade to iOS 4.1? How is this possible, I never saved SHSHs before?

Comment: that's not true. I downgrade to ios 4.3 at the moment.

Comment: Yep, you are right: http://www.ijailbreak.com/how-to-downgrade/ removed my erroneous statement. Thanks for clarifying. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.ijailbreak.com/how-to/how-to-save-your-shsh-blobs-with-tinyumbrella-and-downgrade-using-tinyumbrella/) a helpful guide on using TinyUmbrella, SHSH blobs, and downgrading. Depending on your hardware, downgrading may or may not be possible. I haven't tried downgrading anything since iOS 5 beta on original iPad and iPhone 4. It worked in both cases, but I'm not sure what you have.

The version of iTunes may also play a role in your ability to downgrade. For instance, the latest iTunes may not allow you to restore a version of iOS prior to 5.

Sorry if this wasn't as solid an answer you were searching for. Maybe it'll give you a starting point to experiment, if you have the time though.

Comment: I was able to get iOS 4.3. Dunno how this is possibile. I got no errors. Lucky me? I will stick to 4.3 because it's 50% faster then ios 5

Comment: Cool. Congrats lol